# How to force .Net WebBrowser control to start a new session/process

Tags: c#, .net, session

Requirement: To have two embedded .Net WebBrowser controls that each use a different IE session. Server page sets the user's session. This gets stored in memory and shared across multiple WebBrowser controls (just like tabs)

The way this is handled in standard IE is by selecting File > New Session. This opens up a new IE window in a different process, hence they don't share the same session in memory

The only thing I've been able to do is to end the first WebBrowser's session and therefore start a new one in the second WebBrowser. However this means I lose the first session which the requirement tells me I shouldn't

Ending the browser session is done in following way

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Does anyone have any idea of how WebBrowser controls can each be isolated in a different session/process?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using the current way `WebBrowser` works. You share one session across all instances of `WebBrowser`.

I don't know if there is another web browser control that does support multiple active connections (at least [CefSharp doesn't](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/204)), but I would recommend find a solution that way.

Comment: I'm currently looking at using Awesomium. Looks like WebSessions can be cached individually, hopefully I'll figure it out soon

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I answered myself here. Awesomium is capable of doing this, but not IE

Like it was mentioned before, this can't be done with current .Net WebBrowser. I was able to accomplish this using Awesomium. If you donwload their .Net samples and modify the tabbed browser, you can test this by adding a new WebControl and a new WebSession associated to it. Just make up a new DataPath directory for the new session (i.e. .Cache2)

In my example I edited the following:

Added a new WebSession in TabView.xaml:

```
<awe:WebSessionProvider 
    x:Key="GlobalSession2" 
    x:Shared="False"
    DataPath=".\Cache2" 
    Preferences="{x:Static local:MainWindow.WebPreferences}"/>
```

Modified the rows to add a new row:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Added a new WebControl (and sorrounding borders etc) right after the end of sorroundings of first WebControl. This uses the new Session previously added:

```
<Grid x:Name="browserContainer2" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Border
                                x:Name="browserBorder2"
                                BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" 
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" 
                                Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
                                <awe:WebControl 
                                    x:Name="PART_Browser2" 
                                    Source="{Binding Source2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                    NativeView="{Binding NativeView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                    IsSourceView="{TemplateBinding IsSourceView}" 
                                    IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"
                                    WebSession="{Binding Source={StaticResource GlobalSession}}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ui:MetroProgressBar 
                                Grid.ZIndex="100" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Margin="0,3" 
                                IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsNavigating, ElementName=PART_Browser}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding IsNavigating, ElementName=PART_Browser, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                            <Grid 
                                x:Name="statusGrid2" 
                                Height="25" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                Opacity="0.8">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border 
                                    x:Name="statusBox2" 
                                    Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" 
                                    CornerRadius="0,5,0,0" 
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        x:Name="targetURLBlock2" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Margin="5,0" 
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                        Focusable="False" 
                                        Text="{Binding TargetURL, ElementName=PART_Browser, Converter={StaticResource UrlConverter}}" 
                                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Grid 
                                    x:Name="zoomBox2" 
                                    Grid.Column="1" 
                                    Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border 
                                        Grid.ZIndex="-100" 
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                        Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" 
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" 
                                        BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" 
                                        CornerRadius="5,0,0,0" 
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Margin="7,0" 
                                        Text="Zoom:"/>
                                    <Slider 
                                        x:Name="zoomBar2" 
                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PART_Browser}" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource FlatSlider}" 
                                        Margin="0,0,25,0" 
                                        Minimum="10" 
                                        Maximum="400" 
                                        Width="120" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Value="{Binding Zoom}" 
                                        AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" 
                                        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
                                        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
                                        SmallChange="1" 
                                        LargeChange="10" 
                                        TickFrequency="10" 
                                        Focusable="False">
                                        <Slider.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                                <MenuItem Command="{x:Static awe:WebControlCommands.ResetZoom}" CommandTarget="{Binding}" />
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Slider.ContextMenu>
                                    </Slider>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
```

Then I added a new Source property in TabView.cs to store the second browser's URL:

```
public Uri Source2
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(SourceProperty2) as Uri; }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty2, value); }
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty2 =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source2",
        typeof(Uri), typeof(TabView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

And finally hardcoded two URLs to start the two embedded browsers

```
internal TabView( MainWindow parent, Uri url, bool isSourceView )
    {
        parentWindow = parent;
        this.IsSourceView = isSourceView;
        this.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        this.Source2 = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    }
```